# Can I create the equivalent of a SQL temporary table in databricks?

Tags: databricks

I have a databricks notebook in which I currently create a view based off several delta tables, then update some of those same delta tables based on this view. However I'm getting incorrect results Because as the delta tables change the data in the view changes. What I effectively need is to take a snapshot of the data at the point the notebook starts to run which I can then use throughout the notebook, akin to a SQL temporary table. Currently I'm working around this by persisting the data into a table and dropping the table at the end of the notebook, but I wondered if there was a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section [Pinned view of a continuously updating Delta table across multiple downstream jobs](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/02/04/introducing-delta-time-travel-for-large-scale-data-lakes.html) contains the following example code:

```py
version = spark.sql("SELECT max(version) FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY my_table)")\
  .collect()

# Will use the latest version of the table for all operations below

data = spark.table("my_table@v%s" % version[0][0]

data.where("event_type = e1").write.jdbc("table1")
data.where("event_type = e2").write.jdbc("table2")
...
data.where("event_type = e10").write.jdbc("table10")
```

Comment: Thank you - seems so obvious now!